# Chrome on Android WebRTC volume slider doesnt work when using microphone

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, webrtc

When I establish a WebRTC connection with output and input (video and microphone) on chrome for Android, when controlling the volume slider using hardware keys, I will get shown the volume for the STREAM_VOICE_CALL stream, which is not the right stream for the WebRTC. This make it impossible for the user to effectively control the volume.

I'm guessing this is happening because when I turn on the microphone (with getUserMedia), the system thinks i'm in a call.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Is it expected behavior or a chrome bug?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like its already fixed in latest Chrome version.

Answer (score 1):

Is that how it is built now? At least chromium issue 243506 tells the following:

> Enable audio volume control on Android.
>
> **This is done by setting stream to VOICE which is the only stream type hooking up volume control automatically.**
>   It's required to use matching audio mode and stream type. Otherwise, the volume control doesn't work. That means we have to use same mode
>   for both WebAudio and WebRTC. This leads to the change in audio_manager_android.cc which sets audio to communication mode so that OpenSL
>   stream can use VOICE stream type to adjust volume.

***Bold*** is added by me.

(https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=243506)

Comment: I mean if it uses voice stream, that may be intentional.